# Emacs and MacTex in El Capitan

Tags: emacs, auctex, mactex

I am a newbie to Emacs and have just installed GNU Emacs from emacsformacos.com on OSX "El Capitan" but couldn't figure out how to correctly link Mactex 2015 to Emacs.

- When trying to Latex a tex file I got the following message
   bash-3.2$ latex \nonstopmode\input test.tex
   bash: latex: command not found
   bash-3.2$
- I have create an .emacs file with the following entry only
  (setenv "PATH" "/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin/:$PATH" t)

It seems latex have successfully created a dvi file. I am not sure how correct is what I did ?

- How can I do a pdflatex ?
- Is there a way to configure a shortcut to Latex > Pdf > Preview the results directly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to this forum, do you have an example of your code?

Comment: What version of Emacs/AUCTeX do you have? The relevant variable here is `TeX-PDF-mode`, but it's default value is `t` (i.e., use PDF) in recent versions. Also, you may need to `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin")`.

Comment: @Arne I have a very minimal code like 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Main Title}
\author{{\bf Author}}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Equation can be written as
\[ s^s+x^2=5, \]
\end{document}

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks. Emacs version is 

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)
 of 2015-04-10 on builder10-9.porkrind.org

and Mactex 2015 
https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

Comment: @SeanAllred 
Here is the result of  C-c C-f 
bash-3.2$ latex \\nonstopmode\\input test.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=latex) restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(./test.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (./test.aux)
[1] (./test.aux) )
Output written on test.dvi

Comment: @user75983  You're not using AUCTeX, right?  In Emacs' builtin `tex-mode`, if I press `C-c C-c` the default command is `pdflatex`, but if you want a more advanced *TeX editor I'll suggest you to install AUCTeX from GNU ELPA.

Comment: @giordano Thank you for mentioning AUCTeX. I just installed it and it seems great. Any recommendations or tips for getting more of AUCTeX will be appreciated.

Comment: For sure the `(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)` in your init file gives you access to most of the features AUCTeX provides.  You may want to give a look at the [manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html).  On this site there are also some interesting questions, among them: [Useful shortcuts or key bindings or predefined commands for emacs+AUCTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20843/31416) and [What is your favorite Emacs and/or AUCTeX command/trick?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52179/31416).

Comment: @giordano Thanks. After modifying the .emacs file, I got the following error message when starting emacs

Wrong type argument: listp, t

Any idea about it

Comment: Does `pdflatex` work from your shell?  If yes, then use the package `exec-path-from-shell` to set up the correct path in emacs.  See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10737/2710 .

Comment: @user75983 Without viewing your init file it's impossible to say what's wrong, and this would be off-topic here anyway.  For more Emacs-specific questions there is https://emacs.stackexchange.com/