# Is there a shortcut in AUCTEX/emacs that generates these escape parentheses shorthand for the math environment:

Tags: emacs, auctex

## Is there a shortcut in AUCTEX/emacs that generates these escape parenthesis:

shorthand for "inline math environment"

```
\(  <cursor here>  \)
```

That puts the cursor in the middle of this "mini-environment thing"

## so that I can write Math in the middle of a sentence.

I have tried the cheat sheets and the macros but I cannot get it to leave the cursor in the middle.

Alternatives/tips welcome (I am an undergrad trying to learn AUCTEX in my spare time)

Comment: You could use `C-cC-e math` which is the same thing but I just type `\(` then type the math then type `\)`  that's only 4 keystrokes, it's hard to see how you would get a key combination to enter `\(  \)` and then step past the `\)` at the end in less than 4 keystrokes. Actually I'd do `$` math `$` which is only two keystrokes.

Comment: I've set up that (and similar things for braces and parentheses) in my init file; I explained this in an earlier answer, at `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27921/how-can-i-optimize-the-keyboard-for-frequent-latex-input/27923#27923`

Comment: If you are using auctex, just put `(setq LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace t)` in your init file. When you are in a math environment typing `\(` results in what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AUCTeX gives you have a couple of options out-of-the-box, without defining a function on your own.  They're both described in the manual and aren't mutually exclusive, you can activate both and use them at the same time

#### First: [`TeX-electric-math`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002delectric_002dmath)

```lisp
(add-hook 'plain-TeX-mode-hook
      (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'TeX-electric-math)
              (cons "$" "$"))))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'TeX-electric-math)
              (cons "\\(" "\\)"))))
```

With this code, you can just press <kbd>$</kbd> and get `\(...\)` in `LaTeX-mode`

#### Second: [`LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002delectric_002dleft_002dright_002dbrace)

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace t)
```

With this, you can type `\(` and the closing `\)` will be added after point.

Answer (score 2):

For all my pairing needs I use the great package [smartparenthesis](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens). To include the pairs you require, do as follows:

First, install (using Melpa or whatever) `smartparenthesis` and then load it. I use `usepackage` for that, but the way suggested by the package's author is to simply run this:

```
(require 'smartparens-config)
```

The important code comes now:

```
(sp-with-modes '(tex-mode plain-tex-mode latex-mode)
  (sp-local-pair "\\\(" "\\\)"))
```

Note that you first escape the initial `\`, thus: `\\`, and then the opening parenthesis, thus: `\(`, which results in the complete sequence: `\\\(`. Ditto with the closing ones.

You can add all your beloved `LaTeX` pairs. This is my own full config (partially copied from someone else's):

```
(sp-with-modes '(tex-mode
                 plain-tex-mode
                 latex-mode
                 )
  ;; math modes, yay. The :actions are provided automatically if
  ; these pairs do not have global definition.
  (sp-local-pair "$" "$")
  (sp-local-pair "\[" "\]")
  (sp-local-pair "\{" "\}")
  (sp-local-pair "‘" "’")
  (sp-local-pair "“" "”")
  (sp-local-pair "\\begin" "\\end")
  ;;; tex-mode latex-mode
  (sp-local-tag "i" "\"<" "\">")
  (sp-local-pair "\\[" nil :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p))
  (sp-local-pair "$" nil :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using @Phil Hirschhorn 's excellent examples I made a function which inserts "escape parentheses" when you press Alt-m

> add it to your `.emacs`
>
> `M-m` to activate

```
(defun escape-parentheses ()

  "we insert escape parenthesis for math-mode
   and move the cursor to the center"

    (interactive)
    (progn
        (insert "\\(   \\)")
        (backward-char 4)
    )
)


(global-set-key "\em"     'escape-parentheses)
```