# Do you break typing conventions when typing LaTeX?

Tags: keyboard

Sorry if this isn't relevant, I thought this might be a good place to ask about this.

I am trying to improve my typing (specifically in the numbers row) so that I can type LaTeX faster, but I am finding that it is sometimes awkward to apply this to LaTeX.

For example, conventional typing rules would suggest you should type "$K$" by first holding right-shift and typing '$', then holding left-shift and typing 'K', then holding right-shift and typing '$'. However, I find it much quicker and more intuitive to hold right-shift throughout and press the 'K' with my right pinky on the shift key, and my right middle finger on the 'K' key at the same time.

My first question is: Is this actually faster, or is it just that I have gotten used to it?

My second question is: Is this safe? I know typing conventions also exist to stop people injuring their fingers, and I don't want to be doing something that might give me some kind of repetitive strain injury.

My third question is: If this is ok, where do I draw the line? For example, using the same unconventional technique to type '$U$' is a bit more awkward for the right hand, so potentially more likely to cause injury.

These questions might be easily related so don't feel any need to give an individual response for each one.

Comment: Is there a difference between “right-shift" and "left-shift"? I use very rarely “right-shift”.

Comment: Maybe see also [How can I optimize the keyboard for frequent LaTeX input? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27921/how-can-i-optimize-the-keyboard-for-frequent-latex-input?rq=1)