# Inserting uppercase greek directly into mathmode with fontspec

Tags: math-mode, greek

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56365/198316) solution for inserting lowercase greek directly in mathmode works just fine for me.

However I have not yet been able to use the same trick for uppercase letters.

What went wrong?

Here is a working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\mathcode`ω=\omega
\mathcode`Ω=\Omega

\begin{document}

$$\omega=ω$$ %Just fine!

$$\Omega=Ω$$ %Will not work!

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the assignments at begin document:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathcode`ω=\omega
  \mathcode`Ω=\Omega
}

\begin{document}

\[\omega=ω,\quad \Omega=Ω\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, with `unicode-math` you need no special setup.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\[\omega=ω,\quad \Omega=Ω\]

\end{document}
```