# using unicode-math with math keyboard or hotkeys?

Tags: math-mode, unicode, math-operators, unicode-math

Here is more information about the unicode math-package:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf

A great pro for using unicode math, is that your code is much more readable. But typing all those symbols using alt+xxxx doesn't seem to be a very fast solution.

I was thinking, in theory it could be possible to have a math keyboard ( i mean in hardware form), where you see all those math characters at your keyboard. Would be quite cool, but I have no idea if this already exist.

On the other hand, just designing hotkeys could be (in the end) even more usefull. Does there already exist a (complete) hotkey list for math unicode symbols?

Comment: Maybe you find something useful in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/good-keyboard-layouts-for-typing-latex

Comment: making my own hotstrings now.

Comment: `unicode-math` tells TeX what to do with 2442 symbols.  To cover all of that would take quite an extraordinary keyboard.

Comment: I consider this to really be a duplicate of the question that Caramdir links to.  It isn't really so much about TeX itself but about entering unicode symbols.  autohotkey (which you mention in your answer) is already mentioned there so I am not sure what this question brings that is not already covered.  Maybe you could make that clearer.

Comment: Could also use a character-map app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a keyboard with mathematical symbols and greek letters:
http://terathon.com/blog/a-mathematical-keyboard-layout/

[image]

Some tex editor have options to arrange shortcuts for unicode symbols. For windows users, you can also create hotstrings for unicode symbols using autohotkey:
http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: You should add that autohotkey is for Windows.