# IM (Input Methods) for entering Unicode math on Windows 7 for use with the unicode-math package?

Tags: unicode, unicode-math

On Windows 7, if I need to enter Chinese, I can setup an input method whereby when I type something such as `hao` Windows automatically suggests a list of characters to choose from, among which I can for instance choose `好` by clicking on one of the characters in the list. This is to give an example of how an input method works.

Now my question. Given that several Unicode characters encoding math symbols exist, in order to enter these, it would be cumbersome to enter the numeric Unicode codes for each of these, so it would be useful to have an input method.

Given that the number of keys on a keyboard is about 120, it makes sense to have an input method on Windows so that when turned on in the language switcher in lower-right hand corner, when I type `\int` the integral sign is automatically entered into my text file as a Unicode character.

Without such input method, inputting unicode for use with the `unicode-math` package would be cumbersome. So, what IMs (input methods) are available (perhaps via installable support programs), to enable Unicode math characters to be easily entered?

Thanks.

Comment: You can still use `\int` winth `unicode-math`, just in case this is not clear.

Comment: Is this on-topic? It seems to be about software for inputting characters rather than about TeX. That is, the TeX element here seems irrelevant - it could be about inputting integral signs in LibreOffice or Word.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use Word or LibreOffice to typeset a math document, the quality wouldn't be up to standards. However, I was just trying to understand `unicode-math`. It seems to me that in order for anyone to make effective use of it, and use it as a viable alternative to what has been done in the past, then a suitable input method **must** be available, otherwise it seems to me that `unicode-math` input would be slow, hence useless. Thank you for your clarifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [using unicode-math with math keyboard or hotkeys?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86245/42880). Here's basically the same question for Mac: [Entering unicode math symbols into LaTeX, direct from keyboard, on a Mac](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110042/42880). And the same kind of question has been asked and [answered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222159/42880) for phonetic symbols, so there's precedent for discussing Unicode input here even if it can be used outside TeX. The possibility of efficient Unicode input is key when comparing Xe/LuaLaTeX with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @JasonZentz, precisely. And my post is analogous to the one you just mentioned, except that my question is about math input methods on a PC rather than on a Mac. I hope that someone will be able to answer my question.

Comment: Meanwhile, if someone can explain to me exactly what the `MathUnicode.sty` style file mentioned in the [post's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110042/entering-unicode-math-symbols-into-latex-direct-from-keyboard-on-a-mac) provides, then I would be delighted.

Comment: If no one replies with an already existing math keyboard that will work with Windows, you can make your own using the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).

Comment: @JohnSonderson: The ability to use Unicode math characters directly with `unicode-math` is a side feature, its main purpose is to be able to use Unicode and OpenType math fonts in engines that support them. So whether or not there are suitable input method is of no significant importance to its viability.

Comment: @JasonZentz, configuring the keyboard with MSKLC for entering Unicode math characters is not a real solution: it's neither practical, nor user friendly (reasons: more math characters than keyboard keys, single keyboard keys would be hard to remember (except for natural language letters)). I'm looking for an input method for Windows that can also map more than one key to one math symbol, and the combinations should be intuitive, like the ones given for the Mac [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110042/entering-unicode-math-symbols-into-latex-direct-from-keyboard-on-a-mac).

Comment: @KhaledHosny, the way you phrased it it seems as though `unicode-math` was designed to take Unicode input from another program and not from a human. Is this really true?

Comment: The MSKLC does let you map a symbol to a key sequence rather than a single key. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222159/42880), which describes the way an [MSKLC-built keyboard](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=uniipakeyboard#b47f8dfb) does this for the International Phonetic Alphabet.

Comment: @JohnSonderson: `unicode-math` provides macros for every symbol it supports, so direct Unicode input is optional not mandatory. For all `unicode-math` is concerned `$\alpha \ge a$` is identical to `$ ≥ a$`.

Comment: OK, now I understand. When the LaTeX preprocessor sees the `unicode-math` directives, it replaces the `\ge` with `≥` and so on and thus embeds the Unicode characters in the output document using these predefined conversions from the included style file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/clarkgrubb/latex-input

I've tested it on MacOS.

It acts just like your normal Input Methods for human languages.

Once it has been installed, you are able to enable the feature by adding the LaTeX language through the keyboard/input settings like adding French or Japanese. And then you can input the math symbols with the LaTeX notation.

For more information, check out the README in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text expander tool for that.

I am using aText (on Mac). I have multiple self-defined aliases for math unicode, all started with `jj`. For example, when I type `jjalpha`, aText automatically replace that with α.

Other text expanders should work as well. An input method like Chinese seems an overkill as there are not as many often-used math notations as Chinese.

If you use Mac, I suggest trying aText which is very solid. My only problem is that `jjin` ∈ conflicts with `jjinfty` ∞. So I set `jjinin` for ∈.