# Entering unicode math symbols into LaTeX, direct from keyboard, on a Mac

Tags: unicode, editors, mac, keyboard

I would like my LaTeX files to contain Unicode characters. For instance, I want to see

> ∃x．x ⟶ β

in my text editor, rather than

> \exists x\ldotp x\longrightarrow\beta

Also, I would like to type these characters directly from my keyboard. For instance, I want

- to get "∃" by typing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>,
- to get "β" by typing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, and
- to get "⟶" by typing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd>.

I'm running Mac OS X, and my keyboard has a British layout.

Comment: So by "alt", do you mean the mac option key (⌥)?

Comment: Yep, the key labelled either as "opt ⌥" or as "alt ⌥" depending on your Mac model.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/good-keyboard-layouts-for-typing-latex

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are two separate tasks here: making your keyboard produce the various Unicode symbols, and making those symbols meaningful to LaTeX.

### 1. Producing Unicode symbols from your keyboard

If you're on a Mac, make a `.keylayout` file, put it in the `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` directory, then log out and back in again. Your new keyboard layout should now appear in System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources.

But how does one create this keylayout? I used an editor (such as [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele)) but also ended up doing quite a bit of tweaking by hand. Keylayouts are written in XML, following [Apple's specification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2056/_index.html). My keylayout is called `MathUnicode.keylayout`, and can be downloaded [here](http://pastebin.com/agQYq4AZ). It is based on the British keylayout. I have given my keylayout a custom icon by saving `MathUnicode.icns`(which can be downloaded [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jpw48/MathUnicode.icns)) in the same directory.

I list below all of the key bindings in my layout. Note that, for instance, <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> (which produces `⟶`) means "type <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> while holding down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key". Note also that I have generally avoided notating the <kbd>shift</kbd> key  (preferring <kbd>P</kbd> over <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, and so on) except where it makes the mnemonic more memorable.

---

α (alpha) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

β (beta) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

γ (gamma) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>

Γ (Gamma) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

δ (delta) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

Δ (Delta) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

ε (epsilon) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>

ζ (zeta) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>

η (eta) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

θ (theta) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

Θ (Theta) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

ι (iota) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

κ (kappa) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>

λ (lambda) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>

Λ (Lambda) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>

μ (mu) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>

ν (nu) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

ξ (xi) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

Ξ (Xi) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

π (pi) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Π (Pi) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

ρ (rho) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>

σ (sigma) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>

Σ (Sigma) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

τ (tau) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

υ (upsilon) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>

φ (phi) (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

Φ (Phi) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>

χ (chi) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

ψ (psi) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

Ψ (Psi) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>

ω (omega) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

Ω (Omega) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>

---

ℂ (complex numbers) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

ℕ (naturals) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

ℚ (rationals) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>

ℝ (reals) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

ℤ (integers) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

---

” (closing double quotes) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>

“ (opening double quotes) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>

¶ (paragraph) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>§</kbd>

° (degrees) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>±</kbd>

… (ellipsis) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>

---

⌊ (lower left bracket) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

⌋ (lower right bracket) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

⌈ (upper left bracket) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

⌉ (upper right bracket) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

〈 (left angled bracket) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd>

〉(right angled bracket) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⟦ (double left bracket) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

⟧ (double right bracket) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

---

↑ (up arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>

↓ (down arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>

⇑ (double up arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>

⇓ (double down arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>

← (left arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

→ (right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

↔ (left right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⇐ (double left arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

⇒ (double right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⇔ (double left right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⟵ (long left arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

⟶ (long right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⟷ (long left right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⟸ (long double left arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

⟹ (long double right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⟺ (long double left right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

↦ (maps-to) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⤇ (double maps-to) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⟼ (long maps-to) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⟾ (long double maps-to) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

⇀ (right harpoon) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>

⇝ (squiggly right arrow) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

---

¬ (logical not) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>~</kbd>

∨ (logical disjunction) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>

∧ (logical conjunction) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>

∀ (for all) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

∃ (exists) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>

∄ (does not exist) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>

．(ldotp, the dot in `∃x. p`) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>

⊦ (turnstile) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

⊩ (double turnstile) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

⊧ (models) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

⟂ (bottom) <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd> <kbd>|</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd>

---

∅ (empty set) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

∈ (member of) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>

∉ (not member of) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>

∪ (union) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>

∩ (intersection) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

⫛ (does not intersect) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

⊂ (strict subset) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>(</kbd>

⊃ (strict superset) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>

⊆ (subset or equal) <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd>

⊇ (superset or equal) <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd>

---

∗ (centred asterisk) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>

÷ (division) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>

× (times) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>

｜ (bar) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd>

‖ (double bar) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>|</kbd>

∤ (not bar) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>|</kbd>

◁ (left triangle) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>|</kbd>

▷ (right triangle) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

◇ (diamond) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

∘ (circle) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

· (centred dot) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

⊗ (circled times) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>

⊛ (circled asterisk) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>

⊖ (circled minus) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

⊕ (circled plus) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>

⊘ (circled slash) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>

⊙ (circled dot) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

---

≝ (defined equal) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

≠ (not equal) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>

≡ (equivalent) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

≈ (approx) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd>

≤ (less than or equal) <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd>

≥ (greater than or equal) <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd> <kbd>></kbd>

---

∴ (therefore) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

∵ (because) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

∞ (infinity) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>

∇ (nabla) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

² (squared) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

³ (cubed) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

√ (root) <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

---

I have used this set-up for several years now, and am very happy with it.  It is particularly useful when composing mathematical emails, where LaTeX is not available. The only snag I have found is that in some programs, some keyboard shortcuts that use <kbd>alt</kbd> no longer work. To tackle this, I configured the keyboard shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> so that I can switch back to my default British layout whenever necessary.

### 2. Getting LaTeX to understand Unicode symbols

Note: you're probably better off using XeTeX if you want Unicode in your LaTeX source files. But let's suppose you want to stick with vanilla LaTeX for the time being.

I save the following in the file `MathUnicode.sty` and include the `MathUnicode` package in all my LaTeX files (that is, by putting `\usepackage{MathUnicode}` in the preamble).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Created by John Wickerson, 07 Jan 2010.
% Updated 28 Mar 2010.
% For use with the MathUnicode keyboard layout.

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{stmaryrd}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{183}{\cdot}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{915}{\ensuremath{\Gamma}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{916}{\ensuremath{\Delta}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{918}{\ensuremath{\Zeta}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{920}{\ensuremath{\Theta}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{923}{\ensuremath{\Lambda}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{926}{\ensuremath{\Xi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{928}{\ensuremath{\Pi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{931}{\ensuremath{\Sigma}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{933}{\ensuremath{\Upsilon}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{934}{\ensuremath{\Phi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{935}{\ensuremath{\Chi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{936}{\ensuremath{\Psi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{937}{\ensuremath{\Omega}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{945}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{946}{\ensuremath{\beta}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{947}{\ensuremath{\gamma}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{948}{\ensuremath{\delta}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{949}{\ensuremath{\epsilon}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{950}{\ensuremath{\zeta}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{951}{\ensuremath{\eta}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{952}{\ensuremath{\theta}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{953}{\ensuremath{\iota}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{954}{\ensuremath{\kappa}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{955}{\ensuremath{\lambda}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{956}{\ensuremath{\mu}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{957}{\ensuremath{\nu}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{958}{\ensuremath{\xi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{959}{\ensuremath{\omicron}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{960}{\ensuremath{\pi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{961}{\ensuremath{\rho}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{963}{\ensuremath{\sigma}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{964}{\ensuremath{\tau}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{965}{\ensuremath{\upsilon}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{966}{\ensuremath{\phi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{967}{\ensuremath{\chi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{968}{\ensuremath{\psi}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{969}{\ensuremath{\omega}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8214}{\parallel}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8450}{\mathbb{C}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8470}{\mathbb{N}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8474}{\mathbb{Q}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8477}{\mathbb{R}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8484}{\mathbb{Z}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8614}{\mathbin{\mapsto}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8656}{\Leftarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8657}{\Uparrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8658}{\Rightarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8659}{\Downarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8669}{\rightsquigarrow}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\stackrel{{\scriptsize\rm def}}{=}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8797}{\eqdef}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8870}{\vdash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8873}{\Vdash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8871}{\models}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9121}{\lceil}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9123}{\lfloor}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9124}{\rceil}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9126}{\rfloor}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9655}{\triangleright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9665}{\triangleleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9671}{\diamond}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9675}{\circ}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10178}{\bot}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10214}{\llbracket} % needs stmaryrd
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10215}{\rrbracket} % needs stmaryrd
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10229}{\longleftarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10230}{\longrightarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10231}{\longleftrightarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10232}{\Longleftarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10233}{\Longrightarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10234}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10236}{\longmapsto}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10238}{\Longmapsto} % needs stmaryrd
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10503}{\Mapsto}    % needs stmaryrd
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10971}{\mathrel{\not\hspace{-0.2em}\cap}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{65294}{\ldotp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{65372}{\mid}
```

Comment: You could also use the `newunicodechar`-package, then instead of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{951}{\ensuremath{\eta}}` you can write `\newunicodechar{η}{\ensuremath{\eta}}`.

Comment: @ralfix Yes, that's a sensible suggestion. I tried it, though, and it seems that the `newunicodechar` package doesn't play well with the `utf8x` encoding, and my package doesn't play well without it. So I have to leave it as-is for the time being, unless somebody is able to clarify the situation...

Comment: @JohnWickerson, you say, `I save the following in the file MathUnicode.sty and include the MathUnicode package in all my LaTeX files.`. Can you please fully explain what this setup achieves. What does it do?

Comment: You save the text I gave into a file called `MathUnicode.sty`, and then create a LaTeX file called `foo.tex` or whatever, and have both files in the same directory. In the preamble of `foo.tex` you include `\usepackage{MathUnicode}`; this allows you to use unicode symbols in your `foo.tex` file and have them produced properly in the resulting `foo.pdf`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the hint to use Ukelele. It makes the process surprisingly fast. It took me just about an hour to get a similar keyboard to yours based on my region specific keyboard layout. It's also a lot of fun to tweak it form time to time.

Comment: I have a question: What did editing the XML file by hand enable you do do that Ukelele didn't?

Comment: @mcb My vague recollection is that Ukelele had a few bugs that meant some complicated dead-key sequences came out wrongly, and needed hand-editing.

Comment: One has to restart the machine for the layout to appear in the Preferences, logging in and out is not sufficient.