# Typing latex efficiently/intelligently

Tags: formatting

I have long wondered why there is no piece of software that typesets ASCII math -like people used to write before tex.

In my view tex is great but $ signs for instance should really be facultative. Even many equations should naturally be displayed by the word processor. I'd like to write say:
"Let (x,y)\in R^2 be a solution of
x^2+bxy+x=0
y^4-yx=0"
and have it typeset in a reasonable way as if I had put the dollar signs, the \mathbb, and the equation display in latex. I do not need full control of my output I just want it to look like reasonably written math.

More generally what is the fastest/shortest way to type math to get a tex-like output?

Thanks alot.

Comment: The fastest way is to use `$`. Period. Alternatively you need to use a different interpreter... something like Pandoc.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at Pandoc. I'd like to avoid having to use $ or some such marker, that looks reasonable to me -robots can dance, this should be much easier.

Comment: Would be too ugly to have all `x` typeset with the same fonts.

Comment: @plm No, because you want what is right not what some algorithm guesses. If I put `Let I be ...` how is the system going to convert it to `Let $I$ be ...`?

Comment: How should any reasonable robot distinguish between `a` as a literal and `a` as a math variable? You almost certainly will have to provide some way of indicating what you want rather than relying solely on some form of automation.

Comment: @plm You could write down your file with ASCII math and then send it to one of the consultants listed on the [TUG homepage](https://tug.org/consultants.html).  They will be happy to typeset the formulas in TeX for you.  Of course, they won't do it for free, but I guess that's what you get for being too lazy to type `$` once in a while.

Comment: Henri and Joseph, again I would like a relatively intelligent piece of software that guesses that if I put x\in R I mean x\in\mathbb R. Yes I am leaving some control. If a human reads x\in R he will understand. Can't you guys see that my aim is to type math easily? And about typing $ once in a while, who are you kidding? It's crippling all tex text. There are thousands in any latexed math paper... Please guys, I am not here to bother you, I seek a life changing answer for mathematicians and scientists.

Comment: I wonder if you might find useful the idea of modifying your keyboard to make it easier to type (La)TeX.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1979/86 for some ideas.

Answer (score 7):

You could change the catcode of all symbols you want to reserve for math to `\active` and then let the characters replace themselves by your choice.

I hope, you see for yourself why this is a really bad idea…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter
\let\@in\in
\def\in{\ensuremath{\@in}}
\def\minus{$-$}
\def\reals{$\mathbb{R}$}
\begingroup
\catcode`\^=\active
\catcode`\R=\active
\catcode`\-=\active
\gdef^{\textsuperscript}%
\gdef R{\reals}%
\gdef-{\minus}%
\gdef\textmath{%
  \catcode`\^=\active
  \catcode`\R=\active
  \catcode`\-=\active
}
\endgroup
\begin{document}

\textmath
Let (x,y)\in R^2 be a solution of x^2+bxy+x=0 y^4-yx=0

Right now, this is a really bad idea---for sure!

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this “answer” deserves any upvotes…

Comment: +1 Actually a very useful answer, as it so clearly illustrates the basic issue that math is fundamentally different in parsing, syntax, and semantics from text.  Plus, the preamble makes it very clear that you in fact have to recreate all of math mode by hand.  And the obvious conclusion to your answer is that if I want math mode without delimiters then I have to have delimiters for text.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear I am not fond of typing, I want to write math before all, as easily as possbile, I want to concentrate on other things than the output, just thinking about the math and having it readable in a standard way. It is not about texing it is about having tex-ike output with minimal effort. I don't want to control everything. All the better if I can't make a mathbb when I want to if in 99% times it wouldn't make sense mathematically.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't clear that dropping `$` and explicit font changes really saves anything, it increases chance of error and when combined with the possibility of local macros saves very few keystrokes.

However there are plenty of different implementations of math markup that make less use of `\`  and `{}` notably [asciimath](http://asciimath.org/) and the [Unicode nearly plain text encoding for math](http://unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v3.pdf) which is essentially the [linear input syntax used in Microsoft Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/linear-format-version-3).

Comment: Thanks alot for all the links. For people who delight in typesetting of course adding symbols and controlling everything as in tex is great pleasure but if you want to type as fast as possible it is a hassle. It adds pressing shift+4 each time you want $ and it cripples the text which is already not very readable with ASCII.