# Universal method to combine diacritical mark ˇ with [sz]?

Tags: typography, letters

I cannot combine the hat-pointing-down ˇ with [a-zA-z] but mostly [sz]. 
Pseudocode

```
\[hat-pointing-down][sz]
```

Most probable packages

```
\documentclass{aritcle}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
% character here
\end{document}
```

Unsuccessful attempts

```
\ˇ{Z}
```

How can you type the general character of hat-pointing-down?

Comment: Do you mean the `hacek` character like in `Czech` language ?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I think it is the same as the diacritical mark.

Comment: Traditional way: `\v{s}`, not using `unicode`/XeLaTeX features

Comment: @Masi Did you try simply typing `Ž`?

Comment: @egreg I cannot type the letter with my keyboard so it is not so simple. I cannot find it in OS X Dvorak International.

Comment: @Masi What I can see is that the Dvorak keyboard layout is *very* defective and just provides accents only for French, Spanish and German.

Comment: @Masi have you tried copy-pasting from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_orthography#Alphabet) for instance?

Comment: @egreg Can you please describe how to make Dvorak keyboard layout better? There are much variations in Dvorak layouts in different systems. Priority 2 bug has now been about the layout in Chromebook some months here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=540815&thanks=540815&ts=1444243379#makechanges Dvorak International OS X is good with Scandinavian and German support. Dvorak Linux is deficient without deadkeys. It would be great if you could extend your explanation about how to make Dvorak better

Comment: @egreg This seems to be a relevant thread where to understand better Dvorak's deficiencies http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17511/13173 Please, note that developers need to understand how Dvorak could be improved. It would be great if you could specify those deficiencies.

Comment: @Masi I just stated a fact after looking at the available dead keys. I know nothing about Dvorak keyboards.

Comment: This is a place where your editor could help you. In both emacs and vim you can set up keybindings for high Unicode characters. This makes the keyboard layout less important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The traditional way to get the “háček” diacritic is `\v{}` - but this does not look good with `fontspec` without choosing a particular font)

Using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or `XeLaTeX` the “háček” diacritic can be typed directly, for example `U+0161` for š.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\v{a}
\v{b}
\v{c}
\v{d}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you loaded `[T1]`, you would get the proper glyph for `ď`, `ľ` and `ť`.

Comment: To get the real thing, you should do `\expandafter\v\expandafter{\x}`

Comment: @egreg: Or not using that dreadful `\pgffor` loops at all ;-)

Comment: `\xintFor #1 in {a, b, c, d}\do {\v{#1}}` ...

Answer (score 4):

The best way is, of course, typing directly `š` or `ž`, which many keyboard layouts allow.

Otherwise you can use the standard commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\ha}{% don't bother with this, it's just for showing the code
  \begingroup\catcode`\v=12 \catcode`\c=12 \haa
}
\newcommand\haa[1]{%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}:~#1\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

The háček (Czech), āķis (Latvian), kablys (Lithuanian),
háčik (Slovak), kavelj (Slovene), kuka (Croatian and Serbian)
can be obtained with \TeX{} by prefixing the character
with \verb|\v|:
\begin{center}
\ha{\v{C}}\quad
\ha{\v{c}}\quad
\ha{\v{D}}\quad
\ha{\v{d}}\quad
\ha{\v{E}}\quad
\ha{\v{e}}\quad
\ha{\v{L}}\quad
\ha{\v{l}}\quad
\ha{\v{N}}\quad
\ha{\v{n}}\quad
\ha{\v{R}}\quad
\ha{\v{r}}\quad
\ha{\v{S}}\quad
\ha{\v{s}}\quad
\ha{\v{T}}\quad
\ha{\v{t}}\quad
\ha{\v{Z}}\quad
\ha{\v{z}}
\end{center}

Note that \texttt{fontspec} is able to use the correct
realization of the diacritic in certain combinations.

For the Latvian alphabet, you can do
\begin{center}
\ha{\={A}}\quad
\ha{\={a}}\quad
\ha{\v{C}}\quad
\ha{\v{c}}\quad
\ha{\={E}}\quad
\ha{\={e}}\quad
\ha{\c{G}}\quad
\ha{\c{g}}\quad
\ha{\={I}}\quad
\ha{\={i}}\quad
\ha{\c{K}}\quad
\ha{\c{k}}\quad
\ha{\c{L}}\quad
\ha{\c{l}}\quad
\ha{\c{N}}\quad
\ha{\c{n}}\quad
\ha{\v{S}}\quad
\ha{\v{s}}\quad
\ha{\={U}}\quad
\ha{\={u}}\quad
\ha{\v{Z}}\quad
\ha{\v{z}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, since the Dvorak keyboard allows typing `ˇ` (Alt-Shift-t), `¯` (Alt-Shift-,) and `¸` (Alt-Shift-z), you can also use `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% define the prefixes
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ˇ}{\v}
\newunicodechar{¯}{\=}
\newunicodechar{¸}{\c}

\newcommand{\ha}[1]{% don't bother with this, it's just for showing the code
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}:~#1%
}

\begin{document}

The háček (Czech), āķis (Latvian), kablys (Lithuanian),
háčik (Slovak), kavelj (Slovene), kuka (Croatian and Serbian)
can be obtained with \TeX{} by prefixing the character
with \verb|ˇ|:
\begin{center}
\ha{ˇC}\quad
\ha{ˇc}\quad
\ha{ˇD}\quad
\ha{ˇd}\quad
\ha{ˇE}\quad
\ha{ˇe}\quad
\ha{ˇL}\quad
\ha{ˇl}\quad
\ha{ˇN}\quad
\ha{ˇn}\quad
\ha{ˇR}\quad
\ha{ˇr}\quad
\ha{ˇS}\quad
\ha{ˇs}\quad
\ha{ˇT}\quad
\ha{ˇt}\quad
\ha{ˇZ}\quad
\ha{ˇz}
\end{center}

Note that \texttt{fontspec} is able to use the correct
realization of the diacritic in certain combinations.

For the Latvian alphabet, you can do
\begin{center}
\ha{¯A}\quad
\ha{¯a}\quad
\ha{ˇC}\quad
\ha{ˇc}\quad
\ha{¯E}\quad
\ha{¯e}\quad
\ha{¸G}\quad
\ha{¸g}\quad
\ha{¯I}\quad
\ha{¯i}\quad
\ha{¸K}\quad
\ha{¸k}\quad
\ha{¸L}\quad
\ha{¸l}\quad
\ha{¸N}\quad
\ha{¸n}\quad
\ha{ˇS}\quad
\ha{ˇs}\quad
\ha{¯U}\quad
\ha{¯u}\quad
\ha{ˇZ}\quad
\ha{ˇz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]