# Is there any LaTeX editor that allows you to type less?

Tags: editors

I don't want a WYSIWYG system like Lyx.

I've been using MikTeX with TeXworks for about 3 months and I feel like I've been typing a lot, sometimes my hand hurts as I work mainly in a laptop.

I was wondering if there is any editor that allows you quickly insert certain environments without having to actually type the whole thing, and neither having to copy/paste blocks of your code.

Comment: TeXstudio has autocompletion, so you only have to type the first few characters until you have a unique match and then press tab. http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#features

Comment: Welcome to Te.SX. What about the normal text you want others to read in your document? Isn't that contributing more than the LaTeX markup? Voice recognition software?

Comment: TeXnic Center has most of the math format macros on a menu.  Find it, click it, and viola she is there!

Comment: Most editors have this to some extent. And many have it customisable, too. Kile does, for example. If you're typing more markup than content and you're working on a regular document, though, you're probably doing it wrong. (There may be exceptions, but generally.)

Comment: You may also want to consider configuring your ketboard to suit TeX better, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1979/86

Comment: As others have said, a lot of editors offer some auto-complete, including TeXworks (pressing tab cycles through the available options for a 'stem')

Comment: Write in markdown and export to LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks to all. I downloaded TeXstudio and it is what I was looking for. I'll try it. However, the latest comment about writing in markdown sounds like a good option, butI don't know anything about markdown, so I'll continue using just LaTeX for a while.