# Writing Umlauts in Texmaker Without Repeating Letters

Tags: texmaker

I am new to LateX and have the following problem: I need to write a few larger documents in German using latex. That's why I need a lot of umlauts, too.
When I hold a key (*o*, e.g.) it repeats it at least once (result: *oo*) and after choosing the right accent it writes the number (result: *oo2*) and at last the correct umlaut (*oo2ö*).

So all I want is an *ö* and the shortest I get is *oo2ö*, any ideas how to solve this problem? Copy and Pasting the umlauts or deleting the unnecessary letters are no options, way too slow.

I am using:

- MacOS
- US-keyboard layout
- MacTeX
- Texmaker

I tried turning off the key repeat in MacOS preferences, but that doesn't work. Changing the key repeat speed makes a difference, however. At the slowest option I get the described result, at the fastest option I get like (*ooooooooooooooo2ö*).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Did you consider adding a German keyboard layout?

Comment: Yes, but i am used to the us layout. Looking for an other solution.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381223/how-to-invoke-character-selection-instead-instead-of-key-repeat seems related.

Comment: I think pressing Alt+U and then o (or O, u, U, a, A) should be the most feasable way.

Comment: Personally, I'd try to make do without dead keys. Just redefine RALT-a, -o, -u und -s. SHIFT-RALT-u or similar would then produce uppercase umlauts.

Comment: alt-u then a vowel will give an umlaut/diaresis in the US english keyboard.   I personally use ABC-extended which gives a wider range of extended latin modifiers, but that's partly because I often need to type things like Hradčany or Łódż and I'm not fond of how many central European keyboards want to correct quotes to „…“ rather than “…”

Comment: Special case of [Good keyboard layouts for typing (La)TeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/good-keyboard-layouts-for-typing-latex).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is about how to input characters, which depends on the OS and the keyboard layout, but has nothing to do with TeX and friends.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the babel package, which changes quotation marks and vocals to umlaut.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,german]{babel} 
\begin{document} 


Abc"odef"Aghi"u

\end{document}
```

Later you replace all these with the actual letter. But until finalization, you can just write it all down without worrying too much.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be use the replace option in Texmaker, and regex search for `oo2ö` with the query `[o]*2ö`, and then replacing it with `ö`, by activating the Regular Expression search option.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: (You misunderstood the OP, the "oo2" part represents what the OP *types* instead of what gets typed out.)